# jq: Remove fields form item array

Tags: jq

This is my desired output:

```yaml
[
  {
    "httpRequest": {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/catalog-data-rest/catalog/search.xml",
      "body": {
        "type": "STRING",
        "string": "<request><oid>2.16.840.1.113883.4.292.10.12</oid><startIndex>1</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>",
        "contentType": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
      }
    },
    "httpResponse": {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "reasonPhrase": "OK",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": [
          "application/xml"
        ]
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "XML",
        "xml": "<?xml version= \"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?> <resultSet> <request> <oid>2.16.840.1.113883.4.292.10.12</oid>...",
        "contentType": "application/xml"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //...
  }
]
```

The problem is that my raw source is a bit not clear and I need to clear it up:

```yaml
[ {
  "httpRequest" : {
    "method" : "POST",
    "path" : "/catalog-data-rest/catalog/search.xml",
    "headers" : {
      "content-length" : [ "141" ],
      "content-encoding" : [ ".*" ],
      "User-Agent" : [ "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.19)" ],
      "Host" : [ "preproduccio.gcatalegs.isisscat.intranet.gencat.cat:8443" ],
      "Cookie" : [ "JSESSIONID=0000DVEWfJHnChmIF3Qm8fS7AOG:19pp48tgo" ],
      "Content-Type" : [ "text/xml;charset=UTF-8" ],
      "Connection" : [ "Keep-Alive" ],
      "Authorization" : [ "Basic VVNVTVBJVFNUOkJ4c2w3MjU5" ],
      "Accept-Encoding" : [ "gzip,deflate" ]
    },
    "cookies" : {
      "JSESSIONID" : "0000DVEWfJHnChmIF3Qm8fS7AOG:19pp48tgo"
    },
    "keepAlive" : true,
    "secure" : true,
    "localAddress" : "127.0.0.1:1080",
    "remoteAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
    "body" : {
      "type" : "XML",
      "xml" : "<request><tableName>ET 99CCA</tableName><owner><ownerType>REF</ownerType></owner><startIndex>1</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>",
      "rawBytes" : "PHJlcXVlc3Q+PHRhYmxlTmFtZT5FVCA5OUNDQTwvdGFibGVOYW1lPjxvd25lcj48b3duZXJUeXBlPlJFRjwvb3duZXJUeXBlPjwvb3duZXI+PHN0YXJ0SW5kZXg+MTwvc3RhcnRJbmRleD48cGFnZVNpemU+MTAwPC9wYWdlU2l6ZT48L3JlcXVlc3Q+",
      "contentType" : "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    }
  },
  "httpResponse" : {
    "statusCode" : 200,
    "reasonPhrase" : "OK",
    "headers" : {
      "X-XSS-Protection" : [ "1; mode=block" ],
      "X-Powered-By" : [ "Servlet/3.0" ],
      "X-Frame-Options" : [ "DENY" ],
      "X-Content-Type-Options" : [ "nosniff" ],
      "Strict-Transport-Security" : [ "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains" ],
      "Set-Cookie" : [ "JSESSIONID=0000NOyZg7ww-mcbN2YfxKE-957:19pp48tgo; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly" ],
      "Pragma" : [ "no-cache" ],
      "Expires" : [ "0" ],
      "Date" : [ "Mon, 17 Jul 2023 15:01:13 GMT" ],
      "Content-Type" : [ "application/xml" ],
      "Content-Language" : [ "en-US" ],
      "Cache-Control" : [ "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate" ]
    },
    "cookies" : {
      "JSESSIONID" : "0000NOyZg7ww-mcbN2YfxKE-957:19pp48tgo"
    },
    "body" : {
      "type" : "XML",
      "xml" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><resultSet><request><tableName>ET 99CCA</tableName><owner><ownerType>RE...",
      "rawBytes" : "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlb...",
      "contentType" : "application/xml"
    }
  },
  "id" : "8755ddd1-835c-40fe-870f-decf16242e4e",
  "priority" : 0,
  "timeToLive" : {
    "unlimited" : true
  },
  "times" : {
    "remainingTimes" : 1
  }
} ]
```

How could I remove `httpRequest.headers` and `httpRequest.cookies` from each item in array?

Comment: To remove just the two fields `.httpRequest.headers` and `.httpRequest.cookies`, use `map(del(.httpRequest | .headers, .cookies))`, but that still leaves you with much more than what your desired output contains.

Comment: `heders` is only on `httpResponse` in the desired result. `httpRequest.headers` is removed.

Comment: @0stone0 There's no second object in the sample data. There's another field `.httpResponse` in the first object which isn't included in OP's list of fields to be deleted. Yet, as I have pointed out, in OP's "desired output" even more fields (not just `.httpResponse.headers`) are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete all `headers` and `cookies` from every nested object, use

```
map(.[] |= del(.headers?, .cookies?))
```

###### [Jqplay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6BqCMHyrp_3)

---

If you don't want to remove them from every object, rather just a few, listing each item in a `del` would be enough:

```
map(del(.httpRequest.cookies, .httpRequest.headers, .httpResponse.headers, .httpResponse.cookies))
```

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hW7p1IUNOU_o)

---

If you would like to keep a few hardcoded keys for each `.httpRequest` and `.httpResponse`, you can [`map()`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#map(f),map_values(f)) over them and them update ([`|=`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=)) that key:

```
map(.httpRequest |= { method } | .httpResponse |= { statusCode })
```

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cQ1fx_Xqj-x)

---

Then, based on OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76705819/jq-remove-fields-form-item-array/76705868?noredirect=1#comment135234250_76705868), if you want to specify a few keys inside `.header`, instead of using the short hand, define the key and then use the same update logic to keep a few keys:

```
map(.httpRequest |= { method } | .httpResponse |= { headers: (.headers | { Expires }), statusCode })
```

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fVLf8xm1_UC)

---

As asked in OP's [new comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76705819/jq-remove-fields-form-item-array/76705868?noredirect=1#comment135242625_76705868), on to extend above filter to remove any other top leven keys; We can use the same strategy, create a new object (so we don't need to `del` everything), but update the required keys with the same logic as above

```
map({ 
    httpRequest: (.httpRequest | { method }),
    httpResponse: (.httpResponse | { headers: (.headers | { Expires }), statusCode }),
})
```

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MVGFsPuD6cR)

Comment: Is it possible to select only keys I need? There are more warsted keys than needed keys. I've tested with `map({httpRequest} | map ({method, path}))`, but I d'ont quite figure out how to chain parents keys...

Comment: Nevertheless, I've played with your approach. How could apply deletion keys on `httpRequest` and also on `httpResponse` at the same time?

Comment: Would you like to define the same keys for every nested object? Or each one individual ?

Comment: Individual. The problem is that I need a keys whitelist for `.httpRequest` and a key whitelist for `.httpResponse`.. So in the same filter I'd need to clean `.httpRequest` and `.httpResponse`. Is it possible?

Comment: Please see the last example/demo. That sounds about right.

Comment: Yes, it sounds right. Another last question, how would you apply a nested whitelist for `.httpResponse.headers` only? For example, I only need `.httpResponse.headers.Content-Type`

Comment: Combined with any of those filters from above? Or just as a seperate one?

Comment: Yes, a combination... something like `map(.httpRequest |= { method } | .httpResponse |= { statusCode, headers.Content-Type })`

Comment: Or something like this: `map(.httpRequest |= { method } | .httpResponse |= { statusCode, headers |= { Expires } })`.

Comment: Please see my last edit, it uses the same logic (`|= { key1, key2 }`) to update `.headers` with the keys you'd like to keep.

Comment: Just only one more question. On last example, everything works fine, nevertheless, first level keys `id`, `priority`, `timeToLive` remains on filtered out object. How could I keep them away? I mean I would only need filtering out over `heepRequest` and `httpResponse` and remove other ones... I hope I've explained well.

Comment: I've added another filter, hope this is what you're looking for.